# Pass Image to A ViewController from a Swift File (Which Is Not A ViewController)

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a cropViewController in an extension to get image cropped.  The result is coming in a swift file (which is not a view controller).  But now the image needs to be set in another view controller.

CropViewController being used : https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController

**My View Controller** File has the following element

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class GetPetViewController: UIViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {
    // Initialize Default Value
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet var bPetImage: UIButton!

    @IBAction func bPetImage_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        // Start Action Sheet
        StartImageActionSheet()
    }

    @IBAction func bSavePet_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set The Default Value
        userDefault.set("GetPet", forKey: "senderActivity")
        userDefault.synchronize()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // Tab Functionality
    func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
        return IndicatorInfo(image: UIImage(named: "ic_get_pet"), highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "ic_get_pet"), userInfo: Any?.self)
    }
}
```

**My Second File** (which is not a view controller)

```
import CropViewController
import FirebaseAuth
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
import UIKit

class ImageFunctions {
}

extension UIViewController {
    // Image Action Sheet
    func StartImageActionSheet() {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self as UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate

        // Action Sheet To Select Camera Or Photo Library
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Select Image", message: "Please Choose A Source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {
            (_: UIAlertAction!) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
                self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.uiAlertControllerAction(alertTitle: "Problem With Camera", alertMessage: "Unable To Load Camera", action: "")
            }

        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: {
            (_: UIAlertAction!) in

            imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // For Image Upload To Server Using PHP
    func myImageUploadRequest(image: UIImage) {
        // Initialize User Defaults
        let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard

        // Get The Sender Activity from User Defaults
        let senderActivityValue = userDefault.string(forKey: "senderActivity")

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "someurl")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        // Get The Firebase User
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }

        let param = [
            "desc": user.uid,
            "sender": senderActivityValue!,
        ]

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)

        if imageData == nil { return }

        request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "image", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, _, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            // print("******* response = \(String(describing: response))")

            // Print out reponse body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            // print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

            do {
                let jsonResponseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary

                // print(jsonResponseObject!)

                // Use Swiftly Json to Parse Json Value Into String
                let json = JSON(jsonResponseObject as Any)
                let fileName = json["url"].stringValue

                if param["sender"]! == "GetPet" {
                    let url = "lit-squad.com/files/images/pets/uploads/" + fileName
                    print(url)
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    // For Image Upload To Server Using PHP
    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData()

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let filename = "myfile.jpg"

        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }

    // For Image Upload To Server Using PHP
    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    }
}

// For Image Upload To Server Using PHP
extension NSMutableData {
    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
}

// Image Picker
extension UIViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    // Image Picker Controller Set Selected Image Into Image View
    public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]! as! UIImage

        // Dismiss The Image Picker And Set The Image
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            // Call The Image Cropper
            self.presentCropViewController(image: image)

        })
    }

    // Image Picker Cancel
    public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// Image Cropper
extension UIViewController: CropViewControllerDelegate {
    // Image CropperView Function
    func presentCropViewController(image: UIImage) {
        let cropViewController = CropViewController(croppingStyle: .default, image: image)

        // Commenting This Because It Was Leading To Function Being Run Twice
        // cropViewController.delegate = self

        // CropperView Attributes
        cropViewController.title = "Crop Image"
        cropViewController.aspectRatioPreset = .presetSquare
        cropViewController.aspectRatioLockEnabled = true
        cropViewController.aspectRatioPickerButtonHidden = true

        present(cropViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Image CropperView Finish Cropping
    public func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: CropViewController, didCropToImage image: UIImage, withRect cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int) {
        // bPetImage.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)

        // Call Function To Upload Image To Server
        myImageUploadRequest(image: image)

        cropViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Basically this is not working in the swift file (where I have commented it) but if I use this cropper function without extension in the view controller itself it will work.

```
bPetImage.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

I am trying the following just before `myImageUploadRequest(image: image)`

```
let viewController = GetPetViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
viewController.bPetImage.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

but getting the error : `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to set the image in the bPetImage in the viewcontroller after getting the image in the swift file in cropviewcontroller (as image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I get this correctly you have some other view controller called `MyViewController` which holds the button `bPetImage`. And this button should get the image now. But what you did is set the protocol to a superclass `UIViewController: CropViewControllerDelegate` which has no access to the button.

The quick and easy solution in your case would probably be

```
(self as? MyViewController)?.bPetImage.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

At least I expect that `self` in your case is the `MyViewController` instance. In general this is not a very good procedure. I would create a specific protocol, not a general one. So rather have:

```
extension MyViewController: CropViewControllerDelegate {
```

in this case you can then call it directly (the code you commented out).

But if you really want it the way you have it, to have `UIViewController` respond to `CropViewControllerDelegate` then I simply suggest you to add a new protocol. Consider something like this:

```
protocol SetCroppedImageDelegate {
    func setCroppedImage(_ image: UIImage)
}
```

now you typecast the delegate instead of concrete class:

```
public func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: CropViewController, didCropToImage image: UIImage, withRect cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int) {
    (self as? SetCroppedImageDelegate)?.setCroppedImage(image)

    // Call Function To Upload Image To Server
    myImageUploadRequest(image: image)

    cropViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And you would now extend your `MyViewController`:

```
extension MyViewController : SetCroppedImageDelegate {
    func setCroppedImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        bPetImage.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am reading your answer and trying to make sense of it please be patient i am a little slow

Comment: @DragonFire Not to worry. Take all the time you need :)

Comment: The image is not loading in your answer 1 & 3, answer 2 I am trying to avoid because I want to use this imagecropping function in multiple viewcontrollers... but seems like there is a problem with "self as?" because func setCroppedImage is not getting called (i tried print("functional called") there.

Comment: @DragonFire it seems additional information is needed then on your side. How are the view controllers connected. Who is the delegate in your case then? It should have been `MyViewController`.

Comment: please see i have updated the code with all the code from both the files

Comment: @DragonFire I am confused on how the delegate is being triggered at all since you commented out this code: `cropViewController.delegate = self`. Are you really really 150% sure this is correct and that your delegate method `didCropToImage` did indeed get called?

Comment: Yes it seems to be working.. if I don't comment that part out the func cropViewController gets called twice and image is uploaded to the server twice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196131/discussion-between-dragonfire-and-matic-oblak).

Comment: @DragonFire then the tool you are using to crop your images seems to be broken beyond reasoning. You should consider using another one. Maybe because you used extension on a `UIViewController` which is also a superclass of `CropViewController` there is some logic to call the method internally and it is being called on the controller itself. You may be able to identify and ignore the call on it but it seems incorrect that you would need to do so. In any case, you DO need to set the delegate to self.

Comment: In the end I think (maybe mistakenly) these functions are supposed to be housed in the viewcontroller itself... kind of like onActivityResult in android which doesn't allow them to be called from outside...